# Is it incorrect to use a non-error as the rejection reason for a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

With `try/catch` it's generally considered incorrect to throw a string or other random object. You're supposed to construct a new Error and throw that instead.

Does this also apply to rejected promises?

Comment: It's not strict. If you think an `Error` object is not a fit for you, you can reject with a custom object, or whatever data structure makes sense to you. `data structures > code`.

Answer (score 2):

[The spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-constructor) says, regarding the argument to `reject`:

> Typically it will be an Error object.

So it's *expected* that it will be an `Error`, but it's not essential.  Use whatever is semantically correct in your situation.